# UV maps resetting on its own

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am having an issue with UV mapping ( Blender 2.83, needed for an export plugin) I have never encountered before in years of working with Blender.

I unwrap a portion of a mesh, set the map where I want it, and move on to the next section.   What is happening now, though, is a section that was mapped previously (in same cases, only a few moments) is resetting to a jumbled mess.

I have tried exporting the UV map before moving to a new section, closed Blender and restarted, reloaded the mesh, loaded an earlier version of it, keeps happening. I have been using Blender since 2.4x and never had this happened before.

Comment: hello, could you plese share your file (only the object with your problem)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Ultimately, I fixed it by by deleting the UV maps, splitting the object into smaller parts and mapping each one, then recombing them.
Still not sure what actually went wrong though....